# How can I exclude specified methods and some code of lines in a method from jacoco code coverage?

Tags: java, code-coverage, jacoco

Require - exclude some methods and exclude some code of lines in a method

Comment: Which things have you tried that have not worked for you?

Comment: worked exclude method, <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*Sample.class</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>                                                                                             But want to exclude some specified lines in methods

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comment, use the `exclude/include` as part of your configuration.

Here is [an example](https://www.thecodejournal.tech/2022/04/jacoco-maven-plugin-report-goal-configurations/#ltincludes--ltexcludes).

> Below is an example in which, all classes which has `jacocodemo` in it is package are included except if they have `jacocodemo/strings` in them.

```xml
<execution>
    <id>jacoco-report</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>report</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/jacocodemo/**/*</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/jacocodemo/strings/*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```